# Django: List all where one field combines all its unique values

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I got stuck. Problem I have is that I would like to create a list of `objects.all()` but where all objects, where one `ForeignKey` is the same, should be combined to one entry in a list.

My Model:

```
class TournamentStandings(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player_place = models.FloatField(verbose_name=u"Place")
```

The list I would like to get is something like this:

ID | Player | Tournament| Place
1 | Name_1 | Tournament_1, Tournament_2| Place_on_tournament_1, P_o_t_2
2 |Name_2 |Tournament_1, Tournament_2| Place_on_tournament_1, P_o_t_2

So the `ForeignKey(Player)` would be the one I would like to limit and combine entries. I tried the generic view for objects.all() and the loop in my template:

```
{% for player in ranking_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ ranking_list.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ ranking_list.player }}</td>
    <td>{{ ranking_list.tournament }}</td>
    <td> {{ ranking_list.player_place }} </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

It didn't work. Any hints ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a little bit different aproach. 
I used annotate in my views.py:

```
    ranking_list = TournamentStandings.objects.values('player__name').annotate(Sum('player_points'))
return render(request, 'rankings.html', {'ranking_list': ranking_list})
```

Then in my template I show column with `player__name` and `player_points_sum`. Sorting is done by `webstack_django_sorting` in template so users can decide by wich column and what order they want the results are shown.

template.html:

```
{% load sorting_tags %}
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>{% anchor player__name _("Gracz") %}</th>
  <th>{% anchor player_points__sum _("Punkty") %}</th>
</tr>
</thead>
{% load static %}
<tbody>
{% autosort ranking_list %}
{% for ranking_list in ranking_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ ranking_list.player__name }}</td>
    <td> {{ ranking_list.player_points__sum }} </td>

  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `order_by` to your query so that standings for the same player are sequential, and pass the result into `itertools.groupby` to get "sublists" (all standings for the same player grouped together). You can then process/format those in any way you like.

Comment: On another note, don't forget to use `select_related` to prevent the so-called "N+1 issue".